# How do i search mysql between two dates?

Tags: mysql

Currently my dates are formatted like 01/01/2012.  how do i update mysql records to set date from 01/01/2013 to 2013-01-01 without having to do each date individually?

```
update table set date='2012-01-01' where date='01/01/2012'
```

Comment: What datatype is that column? A proper `date` column does not have a "format". The format is applied by your SQL client when *displaying* that value.

Comment: You should not be storing your dates as `varchar` but as `date` or `datetime` or `timestamp`. This guarantees that SQL can directly operate on dates knowing exactly what date they are (adding, subtracting, comparing, etc). SQL can also format the date into any format you desire for presenting to a user. Storing dates as varchar, to boot, is a lot more space and time expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
UPDATE
    tablename
SET
    date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```